# Return activity result from different activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-stack

I have 2 android applications, say app A and B. Application A starts main activity of app B and sends some data to it using `startactivityForResult()`.

In app B, there are other activities besides main activity which do the processing and they are chained from main activity. When an activity finishes processing, it calls `finish()` and starts the next activity.

The result for app A is obtained only on the last activity in the chain and I want to return it to app A and receive it in `onActivityResult()` callback.

Taking into account that the main activity of app B (which received the intent from app A) is finished, is there any possibility to return the result to app A?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try `BActivity.this.setResult(resultCode, data);` in the last activity.

If it not works, you can change the start type to `startActivityForResult()` of the activity chain in B, that says A > B > B1 > B2 > B3, start method is totally `startActivityForResult()`, then B3 result will return to A.

In Android, the chain will return simultaneous, the interface of B B1 B2 will never show, it seems like that B3 return to A